# Passing string arguments to TestCafe Selector in page model

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, parameter-passing, testcafe

I have a problem similar to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57202155/passing-arguments-to-testcafe-selector-in-page-model/70584127#70584127), I think in that link guys are using typescript files. I have defined selectors in the js files, I tried to do it this way:

```
class Page {
   constructor(sampleText){
       this.optionsButton = Selector('#options').withText(sampleText);
   }
}
export default new Page();
```

but when I try to call selector from test file

```
test('sampleTest', async t=> {
    await t.click(Page.optionsButton('sometext');
)}
```

I got an error:

> ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error: The "text"
> argument (undefined) is not of expected type (string or a regular
> expression).

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2):

`optionsButton` is a property and its value is defined using the constructor so the parameter can only be passed at the moment you create the object like this:

```js
new Page('sometext');
```

It would be better if you write a method in the Page class that returns the selector based on a parameter:

```js
class Page {
  optionsButton(opt) {
    return Selector('#options').withText(opt);
  }
}

export default new Page();
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this is what I needed. Currently I cannot test it because test environment is not working

Comment: '@Romer' thank you, I would like to confirm that your solution works perfectly